# How to get the right toolbar back on Inkscape? It's disappeared

Tags: inkscape

Stupid question really. But I accidentally clicked the [x] on the toolbar on the right (not the one with the snapping functions on it, the one to the left of it) and it closed, and now I have no idea how to get it back? I use it for coloring, line width etc. Help please!

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry, worked it out, just used Shift+Ctrl+F and it popped back up!

Comment: So, to fix up the terms you used: You closed the Fill and Stroke dialog in the dock and now reopened it.

Comment: You can also get it back by simply clicking in the fill or stroke box at the bottom left.

Comment: … or by clicking on the »*Edit object's colors, gradients, ...*« icon in the same toolbar which also contains the three icons for *new, open, save*.